# Would there be plateaus in IQHE in haldane graphene model

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-hall-effect, berry-pancharatnam-phase

It's my understanding that the plateaus observed in the integer quantum hall effect are due to scattering due to impurities in the material. The haldane model for graphene does not include a model for impurities that i know of, so would it not have these plateaus.

As an extra question, I was wondering why the plateaus of the hall resistance for the B-field are not material dependent given that different materials have different amounts of impurities.